# Bash script to copy file by type

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I use `file` command for copying the files in a directory according to their type? I know I can use `file` to find the type of the file, but I don't know how to use it it the `if` condition.

What I want to achieve is this. I need to tidy up my downloads folder. When I run the specific script, I want the files in the mentioned folder to be moved into a dedicated folder, according to its type. For eg, image files should be moved to a folder named "Images", video files to "Videos", executables to "Programs" and so on.

Comment: Do you mean find command and not file?

Comment: I meant file, but if its possible to use find command, I'm open to that too.

Comment: Can you post an example of the files and their extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```sh
for filename in ./*; do
    case $(file -b -i "$filename") in
        inode/directory* | inode/symlink*)
            echo "$0: skip $filename" >&2
            continue;;
        application/*) dest=Random;;
        image/*) dest=Images;;
        text/html*) dest=Webpages;;
        text/plain*) dest=Documents;;
        video/*) dest=Videos;;
        *) dest=Unknown;;
    esac
    mkdir -p "$dest"
    mv "$filename" "$dest/"
done
```

The mapping of MIME types (`-i` option) to your hierarchy of directories isn't entirely straightforward. The `application` MIME type hierarchy in particular corresponds to a vast number of document types (PDF, Excel, etc) - some of which also have designated types - as well as the completely unspecified generic `application/octet-stream`. Using something else than MIME types is often even more problematic, as the labels that `file` prints are free-form human-readable text which can be essentially random (for example, different versions of the same file format may correspond to different detections with different labels, which are not systematically formatted, and so you might get `Evil Empire Insult (tm) format 1997` from one file and `Insult 2000` from another with the same extension).

Probably do a test run with `file -i ./*` and examine the results you get, then update the code above with cases which actually make sense for your specific files.